# Will $.getScript function keep occupying memory

Tags: jquery

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#list">list</a>
<a href="#edit">edit</a>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### init.js

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        var html = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        $('#content').load(html + '.html', function() {
            $.getScript('assets/' + html + '.js');
        });
    });
});
```

This is how I use ajax load file via hash code, I used to put JavaScript in those loaded file by using `script src`, but get warning.

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated`

That's why I change way to load related script file after html be loaded, but I was wonder will it use more and more memory if I load more html page.

Comment: It will, but so would your old method.

Comment: Memory usage is not related to html page load. It is based on content available in javascript. This will be getting cleared only when browser is getting closed

Comment: If the new JS file redefines functions from the old JS file, the old functions will be garbage-collected.

Comment: I don't actually see why you're getting the synchronous request warning.  Nowhere in your visible code are you doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript uses automatic garbage collection, which means it keeps in memory anything that can be accessed, and automatically cleans out the objects and functions that can't. It doesn't matter how they're loaded, whether statically by using `<script>` tags in HTML files or dynamically by using `$.getScript()`.